# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x-\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{x-\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}}$$

$\sin{x}$ is a bounded function, but I still have no clue what to do. Any hint?

Comment: Hint $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ because $\sin x$ is bounded. So $$\frac{1-\frac{\sin x }{x}}{1+\frac{\sin x }{x}} \to 1.$$

Comment: $\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}} = \left( 1-\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right) / \left( 1+\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right)$

Comment: What if $x=1\text{ trillion?}$ Then we have $$ \frac{1\text{ trillion} - \text{a tiny amount}}{1 \text{ trillion} + \text{the same tiny amount}} \approx 1. $$ The approximation can be made as close to the truth as desired by putting a big enough number in place of $1\text{ trillion}.$ So the limit is $1. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

$$
\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x}=\frac{x+\sin x-2\sin x}{x+\sin x}=1-\frac{2\sin x}{x+\sin x}
$$

It should be easy enough to evaluate the limit using the rightmost expression.

Answer (score 2):

The bounds $\frac{x\mp1}{x\pm1}=\left(\frac{1+1/x}{1-1/x}\right)^{\mp1}$ provide an easy use of the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard about the squeeze theorem? Here I present its statement and the corresponding proof.

> Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space, $E\subseteq X$, $x_{0}\in X$ such that $x_{0}$ is an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in \textbf{R}$. Moroever, let us consider that $f:X\to\textbf{R}$, $g:X\to\textbf{R}$ and $h:X\to\textbf{R}$ are real-valued functions s.t.
> \begin{align*}
> f(x)\leq g(x) \leq h(x)\quad\wedge\quad\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}h(x) = L
> \end{align*}
> Thus we can conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}g(x) = L$.

**Proof**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta_{1} > 0$ and $\delta_{2} > 0$ s.t. for every $x\in E$ the next implications hold
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta_{1} \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon\\\\
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta_{2} \Rightarrow |h(x) - L| < \varepsilon
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Based on the previous results, we may claim that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x) < L + \varepsilon \Rightarrow |g(x) - L| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_{0};x\in E}g(x) = L$.

At your case, we are taking limits as $x$ approach $+\infty$, but the same reasoning applies. It suffices to consider the following definition:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = L \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists N\in\textbf{R}_{\geq0})\,\,\text{s.t.}\,\,x > N \Rightarrow |g(x) - L| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

To solve the proposed exercise, notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x - \sin(x)}{x + \sin(x)} = \frac{1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{1 + \frac{\sin(x)}{x}}
\end{align*}

Since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ and $1/x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)} = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: That theorem is familiar, but I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What if $x=1\text{ trillion?}$ Then we have $$ \frac{1\text{ trillion} - \text{a tiny amount}}{1 \text{ trillion} + \text{the same tiny amount}} \approx 1. $$ The approximation can be made as close to the truth as desired by putting a big enough number in place of $1\text{ trillion}.$ So the limit is $1.$